# Handling colon in element ID with jQuery when using jquery.scrollTo

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using the jquery.scrollTo plugin on my site as follows:

```
$('a[href^="#"]').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(window).stop(true).scrollTo(this.hash, 
       { duration: 500, interrupt: true, margin: true });
});
```

This works 100% fine for most anchors. However, when scrolling to elements that contain a colon in the name, it causes jQuery to throw an exception. So, for example, the following HTML does not scroll as it should:

```
<a rel="footnote" href="#fn:1">1</a>
...
<ol>
    <li id="fn:1">
        Footnote 
        <a class="footnote-return" href="#fnref:1">
            <sup>[return]</sup>
        </a>
    </li>
    ...
</ol>
```

This is especially a problem when rendering markdown footnotes. The markdown processor that I use ([Black Friday](https://github.com/russross/blackfriday)), as I assume most other processors, render footnotes with a convention that contains a colon in every cross-reference.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is escape the colons (`.replace(':', '\\:')`):

```
$('a[href^="#"]').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(window).stop(true).scrollTo(this.hash.replace(':', '\\:'), 
    { duration: 500, interrupt: true, margin: true });
});
```

Working example:

```js
$('a[href^="#"]').click(function (e) {
 e.preventDefault();
  $(window).stop(true).scrollTo(this.hash.replace(':', '\\:'), 
    { duration: 500, interrupt: true, margin: true });
});
```

```css
ol {
  margin: 90vh 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-scrollTo/2.1.2/jquery.scrollTo.min.js"></script>

<a rel="footnote" href="#fn:1">1</a>
...
<ol>
    <li id="fn:1">
        Footnote 
        <a class="footnote-return" href="#fnref:1">
            <sup>[return]</sup>
        </a>
    </li>
    ...
</ol>
```

Comment: Thank you, Andrei! It works like a charm. I appreciate your kind and complete answer.